# Why this brings about SIGABRT error?

Tags: objective-c, ios, button, tags

I have some sources below.

```
- (void)Button:(UIButton *)button {

    NSString *imageName = ((UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:button.tag]).titleLabel.text; 

}

- (void)viewDidLoad { 

    NSMutableArray *_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSInteger iCount = [_array count];

    for (i = 0; iCount > i; i++) {

        UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        btn.titleLabel.text = [[_array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"FILE"];
        btn.tag = i;
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(Button:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:btn];
        [btn release];

}
```

When I access Button method with 0 index tag, I get SIGABRT error.
What can I do ?

Comment: you get this error, because the self object that you have passed is actually view controller , not button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your console output properly, by default every view has the tag '0', so it can be crashed because it is taking some other view besides of uibutton, and may be that view don't not have the **titleLabel** property.Because it is the property of UIButton.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView titleLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x98053a0'
*** First throw call stack: blar blar..

Comment: **[UIView titleLabel]:** it should be **[UIButton titleLabel]**, it means - [self.view viewWithTag:button.tag] this return UIView here.(your current view (which you access by 'self')) ..you need to start button tags with 1 or something else..but not with 0. So it won't be clash with any view.